# Making Bootstrap Validator ignore hidden fields

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get bootstrapvalidator to ignore the required attribute of a hidden field. (hidden is removed to make field visible and required when user checks a certain radio box - that bit works fine!)
All online solutions I can find advise doing this:

$('#invitation').bootstrapValidator.validate({ excluded: [':hidden'] });
 (Where invitation is the ID of the form I am validating.)

This seems to have no effect and hidden field is always required.

Comment: does the input have type="hidden" to match the :hidden selector or are you just making it so it's not visible via css? Can you share your html?

Comment: I was doing it by css, as in:
<div class="form-group row">
   <div class="femalefirstname hidden">
  <label for ="femalefirstname" type="text" id="femalefirstname" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Partner's Name</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control required text" type="text" maxlength="15" ....

But just tried adding hidden to input type and that only hides the input whereas the object is to hide the whol DIV. So I'm guessing that I need different code to ensure a CLASS that is hidden is not validated as required?